# smoothscroll view positioning in android

Tags: android, opengl-es

i am using a list view in which i want to directly shift to particular position when i run my code. i m using listview.smoothScrollToPosition(22) which will show the scrolling effect.. which i do not want to show. i want to directly display 22 position of list view.
i used other methods like listview.setselection(), listview.scrollTo() which doesnt work?? 
Kindly, help me out

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setSelection` is what I use in a public domain app I develop. You can read the code [here](https://github.com/appamatto/dhammapada-android/blob/master/src/com/appamatto/dhammapada/ReadingActivity.java). It scrolls the `ListView` to the position I specify.

Perhaps you could post your code if this method isn't working for you?

Comment: Thank u so much.. I got it using set set selection.